# A sequenceNumber like attribute in pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I acknowledge that on the receiver side, there is an attribute publish_time that can be used for sorting out the order of messages. However, unlike the sequenceNumber attribute in SQS, the publisher side returns a future object and I don't find any useful information about the timestamp that the message was successfully delivered to the topic.

Therefore, is there a practice I can do so that there is an sequenceNumber like attribute?